# Changing profile name will make fellow members unhappy?

Tags: discussion

I am an active member on Stack OverFlow. I would like to change my existing user name to something else. But, I have a problem. On some sites, they don't allow members to change the user name saying it will make the fellow members angry. Is that true for Stack Overflow? I respect all the people who helped me in my questions.

- Will changing my user name make them disappointed/angry?
- Have you ever changed your user name? If so, what was the result?

I have accidently changed my profile name, because I needed to try to see how it works. I kindly request a moderator to change my user name back to the previous one.

Comment: Active Member ? you have created your profile 11 days ago, visited meta today first time !!!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. OK, 11 days, but for those days, I am active, yes, very active :D

Comment: Why would it ever make someone *else* angry if you change your user name?

Comment: @TheEstablishment some people are easily angered.  Look at Glenn Beck!

Comment: @ScottWilson: where?

Answer (score 9):

You can change your name once every 30 days.  For awhile, people were changing their names every five minutes, and it was just too confusing.

Flag one of your posts for moderator attention, and ask for the name change.  Make sure you get the spelling and capitalization the way you want it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Robert. I think this is the way to do it :)

Answer (score 2):

A warm welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) site.

You can change your profile name as Robert suggested. For the rest of the question, here is the answer from **my point of view**.

- **Will changing my user name make them disappointed/angry ?**

People here are for questions and answer, means in reality they do not know each other then how can be they disappointed or angry ? There is no harm in changing profile name. **Remember that you are here for asking and answering questions and to help others**.

[Just Be Civic and Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette). Concentrate on Questions and Answers Only.

- **Have you ever changed your user name ?**

Not me but my colleague (I would not like to reveal her name unless moderator ask me so), she always keep changing her name. Well there is a secret reason behind it, which is not to track her in "Frequently in rooms" and "currently in rooms" (you will know this once you start using chat a lot).

Comment: Why won't she want to be trackable? Golden rule of the Internet: If you don't want others to know what you're doing (on a public site), _don't do it_.

Comment: Only one user's approval is required here for `suggested edit` ? @YannisRizos  ,

Comment: @lucifer 2 users is only for SO, IIRC

Comment: Please visit [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3376) here it shows, only you have approved, while on Stack OverFlow, two user's approval is need @YannisRizos

Comment: Sorry !!!, what is the meaning of IIRC @TimManishEarth ?

Comment: Ah, yes, you need 2 users' approval only on SO, on MSO and other Stack Exchange sites you only need one user to approve your suggested edit.

Comment: ok fine, thanks for this information YannisRizos & TimManishEarth

Comment: If I Recall Correctly

Comment: @lucifer yeah, but why would she want to not be tracked?

Comment: Hmm, maybe.. But that brings me back to my point. _If you don't want others to know what you do on the (public) Net, don't do it_. Though it's her choice and this discussion is irrelevant here.

Comment: yeah, agree with you.

Comment: @Tim: I don't think there is anything called such golden rule :)

Answer (score 0):

Posting new Questions and answering existing Questions (the entire point of the sites) also seems to make some users unhappy so you can't please everybody.

I say change your name when it makes sense to change your name, don't worry about other users. The 30 day restriction as mentioned by [Robert Harvey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132768/141346) keeps from the changes being destructive.

If comments get messed up, it shouldn't matter- nothing should be in the comments such that if the comments weren't there the posts become unusable.